# Trying to loop over an array of Custom class objects

Tags: arrays, swift, object, for-loop

I have a data mod that looks like this:

```
class CurrencyModel {
    var currencyName = ""
    var currencyCode = ""
}
```

I'm trying to loop over all of these objects and create an array of currencyNames.

Here is how I'm trying to do that:

```
var currencies = [CurrencyModel]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    for names in currencies{
        let name = currencies[names].currencyName
        namesArray.append(name)

        print(namesArray)
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[CurrencyModel]' with an index of type 'CurrencyModel'

Comment: Why don't you concentrate on the [former thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52282879/6541007) of yours?

Comment: Mostly because it's not the same question. It's related but the other question I was I'm trying to implement the sectionIndexTitles function. Here I'm asking about how to loop over custom objects. I've been asked before to only ask one topic per question. So that's what I was doing.

Comment: The two are not exactly the same, but this is a big part of the former one. That's true you should _ask one topic per question_. But separating too closely related things may makes you difficult to get the best solution for your specific issue. You could wait till someone told you your former question contained multiple topics.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time. I thought I was doing the correct thing. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. It is sometimes hard to judge what is the proper way. I believe you can do it better next time. Hope your issue will be solved soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
let name = currencies[names].currencyName
```

as `currencies` is an array ( `[CurrencyModel]`) to subscript it needs an integer value like `currencies[0]` , but you send `names` instead which is of type `CurrencyModel`

You need

```
var namesArray = [String]()
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  namesArray = currencies.map{$0.currencyName}
}
```

**OR**

```
currencies.forEach { namesArray.append($0.currencyName)}
```

**OR**

```
for names in currencies {  // not perferred 
    namesArray.append(names.currencyName)
}
```

//

**Edit:** then use

```
namesArray = Array(currencies.map{$0.currencyName}.prefix(1))
```

Comment: What if I want to do something like this?
namesArray = currencies.map{$0.currencyName}.prefix(1)

Answer (score 2):

`currencies` is a `[CurrencyModel]` (an array of `CurrencyModel`).

The loop `for names in currencies` iterates that array. `names` will be each individual `CurrencyModel` object in the array.

So the line:

```
let name = currencies[names].currencyName
```

should be:

```
let name = names.currencyName
```

Of course the entire `for` loop can be replaced with one line:

```
let namesArray = currencies.map { $0.currencyName }
```